# how to fix NXDOMAIN rerror

Tags: github-pages

I have tried to give custom domain to my website but the dns check gives error and can't enforce https when I search for my website it gives me this error

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How to solve this problem?